# to remove password from pg Admin 4

Tags: javascript

In Postgres , Is it possible to connect database without password. If it is possible, then please tell me how I remove password from pg Admin 4? And I want to ask too that if it is possible to change my port from 5433 to 5432 ?

I am trying on Pg Admin 4 settings.